# Debugging localhost with fiddler

Tags: debugging, http, localhost, fiddler

I've done a search and there appears to but a lot of information - but just not the answer.  I want to be able to see the traffic going to and from my local ASP.NET debug session, hopefully in fiddler.  Any idea on how to configure for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical - just as I post I find the answer.  All you have to do is add a dot so the URL in your browser is such http://localhost.:2546/Default.aspx. Fiddler will now pick this up.

Comment: There are somewhat better solutions: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: What is the disadvantage of using 'localhost.'? I think this especially elegant. Why do you suggest the solutions on the fiddler-page are somewhat better?